# How can i make it cloudy and gray?

Tags: sutras, grey

I understand that the [storm gods are the cause](https://suttacentral.net/sn32.55/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin).  I hope the sun never returns.  How can I appease or offer those gods to have my wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SN 42.6](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.006.than.html) suggests that "prayer", and various ritual actions, won't change the physical properties of something or physical events, specifically that they won't make a boulder float nor oil sink in water.

[SN 2.10](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn02/sn02.010.piya.html) suggests that an Asura cannot make the sun to never return.

[AN 5.43](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.043.than.html) says that various things "are not to be obtained by prayers or wishes" but instead by "following the path of practice" which leads to them. I interpret that more generally than only those five.

Answer (score 1):

For those seeking a bargain, a warning:

> [MN131:3.9](https://suttacentral.net/mn131/en/sujato#mn131:3.9): Today’s the day to keenly work—
> [MN131:3.10](https://suttacentral.net/mn131/en/sujato#mn131:3.10): who knows, tomorrow may bring death!
> [MN131:3.11](https://suttacentral.net/mn131/en/sujato#mn131:3.11): For there is no bargain to be struck
> [MN131:3.12](https://suttacentral.net/mn131/en/sujato#mn131:3.12): with Death and his mighty hordes.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you wish that ? Gods have their own game to play. You can join the game by following the God of rain and thunder. Even then you will only be part of the game. And it will happen only when the conditions are met. Everything happens based on conditions of the game.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is found in [Saṁyutta Nikāya 32.3–12](https://suttacentral.net/sn32.3-12/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin).

> “Sir, what is the cause, what is the reason why someone, when their
> body breaks up, after death, is reborn in the company of the gods of
> cool clouds?”
>
> “Mendicant, it’s when someone does good things by way of body, speech,
> and mind. And they’ve heard: ‘The gods of cool clouds are long-lived,
> beautiful, and very happy.’ They think: ‘If only, when my body breaks
> up, after death, I would be reborn in the company of the gods of the
> cool clouds!’ They give food … drink … clothing … a vehicle … a
> garland … fragrance … makeup … a bed … a house … a lamp.. When their
> body breaks up, after death, they’re reborn in the company of the gods
> of cool clouds. This is the cause, this is the reason why someone,
> when their body breaks up, after death, is reborn in the company of
> the gods of cool clouds.”
>
> Ten Discourses On How Giving Helps to Become a Cool Cloud God